# Shoot email after confirmation of purchase of 1 specific product

Tags: magento2

I have a specific product that when it is purchased and payment confirmed, I need to send a personalized email just for this product, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this, one way is to create a custom module with an observer for the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` this will let you retrieve the order and check for the product sku that you want to send an email notification for:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;
    
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

    class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
    { 
    
        protected $orderRepository;
    
        public function __construct(  
        OrderRepositoryInterface $OrderRepositoryInterface
        ) {
            $this->orderRepository = $OrderRepositoryInterface;
    
        }
    
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
        {
    
               $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
               $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);           
               $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
               $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    
   
              foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
              {
                    
                    if ($item->getSku() === 'EMAILNOTIFICATION-SKU')
                    {
                       // Send an email to $customer_email
                    }
    
              } 
    
        }
}
```

Ideally you should try and send the email asynchronously so as to avoid delays in the frontend customer order completion.

Another way would be to create a plugin around the existing order notification process that also checks for your SKU and sends an additional email with the order confirmation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will follow these steps and let you know if it worked!